# Refresh TableView items upon selecting an item from a Spinner instead of just concatinating it

Tags: java, android

I have a problem on displaying th JSON Result in my tableView wherein instead of clearing the tablerows before inserting the fetched data, it just concatinates the new data from the old ones and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

First I have a JSON Parser which gets all of the information based on the selected city and dates and I think there is no need to show that part but I just add the data into List Array then do this part.

```
public void showinfo(){
    // Get the TableLayout
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    tl.removeAllViews();

    Log.v(KahelTag, "eventsCleared");

    // Go through each item in the array
    for (int current = 0; current < infoID.size(); current++)
    {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(100+current);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

       //CREATE TEXT VIEW FOR INFO1
        final TextView info1 = new TextView(this);
        clubName.setId(200+current);
        clubName.setText(info1.get(current));
        clubName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        clubName.setTextSize(12);
        clubName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        clubName.setTag(infoID.get(current));
        clubName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        clubName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(info1);

        //CREATE TEXT VIEW FOR info2
        TextView info2 = new TextView(this);
        eventName.setId(current);
        eventName.setText(info2.get(current));
        eventName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        eventName.setTextSize(12);
        eventName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        eventName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 120, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(info2);

      //CREATE TEXT VIEW FOR INFO3
        TextView info3 = new TextView(this);
        eventDate.setId(current);
        eventDate.setText(info3.get(current));
        eventDate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        eventDate.setTextSize(12);
        eventDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        eventDate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(info3);

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    }
}
```

Now I show that info after setting the content view with showinfo(); 
And now for the spinner part. It just call again the JSON codes to change parameters then Display the info out in the table again. But It doesn't work as I wanted since as I said above it just concatinates the data. By the way, I have two parameters that is passed for my JSON text. Here's the code for the spinner:

```
    Spinner spinParam1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner spinParam2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


    spinParam1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            Object specify_param1 = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(specify_param1.toString() != "All"){
                getEvents(specify_param1.toString(),null);
                showinfo();
                Log.v(KahelTag, "showinfo");
            }
            else
            {
                getEvents(null,null);
                showinfo();
                Log.v(KahelTag, "elseshowinfo");
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            getEvents(null,null);
            showinfo();
            Log.v(KahelTag, "nothingshowinfo");
        }

    });

    spinParam2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            Object specify_param2 = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(specify_param2.toString() != "Any"){
                getEvents(specify_param2.toString(),null);
                showinfo();
                Log.v(KahelTag, "showinfo");
            }
            else
            {
                getEvents(null,null);
                showinfo();
                Log.v(KahelTag, "elseshowinfo");
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            getEvents(null,null);
            showinfo();
            Log.v(KahelTag, "nothingshowinfo");
        }

    });
```

Any revisions that I need to make for this to work the way I wanted? Thanks!

Comment: What is info1 and info2 and info3 ? shouldn't you add eventdate, eventname, clubdate, instead?

Comment: edited. haha! sorry I haven't noticed it. I edited the variables for easier viewing. sorry I lost track on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't noticed it but the main cause of the problem is the JSON String array where I store all of the data which is why it concatenates the data from the previous output. Solved the problem by clearing out the arrays first before parsing JSON string. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way i'd do

```
tl = new TableLayout();
```

But why don't you use listview with a custom adapter instead, it sounds a lot more like what you need. Then you dont need to create x100 tablerows etc.

Comment: I prefer tables since it's way easier for me to customize it than listview and applying it on my layout is also easy. Anyway, I don't get the part of tl = new TableLayout();. Well as you can see my Table Layout is already set and all I want to do is to clear the rows inside that table but it doesn't work the way I expected it. :)

Comment: And that's why I tell you to recreate the table instead of just trying to clear its children.

Comment: Tested it but on a way that I need to setContentView into the content of the tableLayout. And now I think I need to set the content of the TableLayout into the TableLayout generated but I don't know what to do and how to. haha!

Comment: Dont understand you, what has that got to do with setContentView? 
Anyways, change to listview, this is not the point of TableLayout.
Listview + xml for listitem + an adapter that extends arraylistadapter will be much more functionel and much more readable.
If you need help with that, ask.

Comment: haha! already solved the main cause of my problem bro. Thanks for helping me.